# how to check if a javascript object has an instance of a particular object

Tags: javascript, object, constructor

say i have an array **x** and a constructor

```
function Road(footpath,divider,length,lanes){}
```

and

```
x[1] = new Road(1,1,1,1);
```

now how do i determine that x[1] is an object of type Road?

Comment: use instanceof like x[1] instanceof Road

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple like this

```
if(x[1] instanceof Road) {
    //Hey, you have a road!
}
```

Comment: I tried that but it returns false probably because i add more to it like x[1].children ="Something else"; now if i say x[1] instanceof Road it returns false

Comment: Adding an attribute to your object doesn't seem to be your issue; have a look at a working example: http://jsbin.com/zikivobese/2/edit